# php date function returning wrong answer?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the first of the current month in PHP, using the `date` function, however, the output isn't quite what I'm after, even if I manually change the date string.

```
//get Current date
$dat=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

//date with same month and year but first day of month in the above date
$d=date("Y-M-01",strtotime($dat));
//date with first day of month printed correctly
echo $d;

//day not printing correctly. First day is not printing. 
echo date('N',$d);
```

This is output I'm getting:

```
//This is output of date after setting first day of month
2013-Dec-01

//but when above printed date is used in as date('N',above Printed date)
//the result is 4 and not 1
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo date('N',strtotime($d));
```

Also in PHP [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) 1 stands for Monday and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want day you need to write.

```
echo date('d', $d);
```

And check this to get more info:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `date` function expects second argument to be a timestamp, you're giving it a string (`$d`).

Second of all, `N` in the date format is a numeric representation of the day of the *week*, not month. What you're looking for is `d`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php